# How to keep ionic app running when minimized

Tags: ionic-framework

I built an app with ionic, they is a process in the app that I want it to run for a long time, it's working but when I minimize the app, it stops working, I tried using ionic background service but it's still the same thing, pls how can I make the app to continue working even in the background.

The process I am running is to listen to change in clipboard, and if the content of the clipboard returns true, I want to send it to the database, it's only working if I an using the app, but what I am coping is from another app

Comment: use `platform.resume()` or `background Mode`.

Comment: How can I use it

Comment: see documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode

Comment: It mean you want to copy a data from one application and save it to another. app without opening that app?

Comment: its not working in android 10